# How to detect if a photo was taken with the iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit

I know how to access the photos on the iPhone using the APIs from PhotoKit (e.g. PHAsset, PhotoLibrary, ...) from objective-c.

How can I safely determine if a photo was taken with the iPhone my code is running on? Are there any properties (e.g. of PHAsset or EXIF) that can reliably be used for that? My app should only use photos that were actually taken using the current phone's camera.

Comment: I doubt it. It'll tell which model iPhone but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to get metadata of image.
In case of using PHAsset you can create some extension for getting of metadata. For example:

```
-(void)requestMetadataWithCompletionBlock:(PHAssetMetadataBlock)completionBlock{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editOptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];
        editOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [self requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
            CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionBlock(image.properties);
            });
        }];
    });
}
```

In the dictionary can find camera maker.
For example:

```
      ...
      Make = Apple;
      Model = "iPod touch";
      ...
```

And also worth to take a look at [ImageIO Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio), here you will find some default keys for metadata parsing and other useful info.

But there are no public API that tell you that the photo was taken by current iOS device.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: And this doesn't answer the question. The question is asking if the photo was taken with the current iOS device that the app is running on.

Comment: @RomanTsymbaliuk thank you for pointing out how to access the metadata. However the important part of my question is to reliably determine that the photo was taken with the device my app is running on. You also mention that there's no public API to tell me that. I'm still hoping for a different answer. If none comes up, I'll mark your post as the answer.